# Print columns of my dataset JAVA

Tags: java, transpose

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
id1 1 2 3 4  
id2 2 6 6 0 
id3 3 4 2 2
id4 4 3 3 1
id5 5 6 6 5
id6 6 2 4 6
```

The first line of the frame is the first data point. the second is another data point, etc...

my DataPoint Class is as follows:

```
public class DataPoint {
    private ArrayList<Integer> values;
    private String id;
}
```

So for id1 the fields will be: id = id1, and values = {1, 2, 3, 4}, etc. 
What I'm trying to do is print the DataPoints by columns...

So for the above input, my output should be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 6 4 3 6 2
3 6 2 3 6 4
4 0 2 1 5 6
```

I can't modify the above format of DataPoint because I'm too far ahead in my project and I can't afford to change all of the data structures :/

Is there any way to transpose my results without changing the data structures?

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for (DataPoint dp : dataPoints) {
        System.out.print(dp.values.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```